# How To Resize An Image In An Excel Cell VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm New to vb.net or rather to all programming. I've already tried searching for my answers for every links related to my question yet I can't still find any answers or I just don't understand the codes.

My question is how to resize the image in an excel using VB.NET. My codes in inserting an image to an excel already works but there are larger images that i wanted to be in a fix size.

Here's my code for inserting an image, please help me how to resize the image into a fix 2 inch or whatever. PLEASE...

```
Private Sub AddPicture_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles AddPicture.Click

        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            'Start Excel
            APP = New Excel.Application
            'Open an existing excel application
            Dim workbook = APP.Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Users\user\My Documents\
            PROJ 141\System\Book1.xlsx")
            Dim worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
            Dim oRng As Excel.Range
            Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

            With worksheet
                oRng = DirectCast(.Cells(32, 1), Excel.Range)
                oRng.Cells.Select()

            End With

           'Add a picture to excel
            APP.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Select()
            workbook.Save()
            APP.Workbooks.Close()
            workbook = Nothing
            worksheet = Nothing
            APP.Quit()
            APP = Nothing 

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy I solved my own question...

I just change this line of code:

```
APP.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Select()
```

into:

```
With APP.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
            .Width = "50"
            .Height = "50"
            .Placement = 1

        End With
```